# How I can pass an associative array in a codeigniter login form

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have this login form that looks like this :

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Login page</title>
<link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/3rd-party/loginstyle.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="login">
  <div class="login-triangle"></div>
  
  <h2 class="login-header">Log in</h2>

  <form class="login-container">
    <p><input type="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
    <p><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Log in"></p>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to insert this php forms into my first login script, I read about form attributes in codeigniter but I'm quite new and I don't understand how exactly works, this is my vanilla php that I want to insert  above :

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Login page</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
 <h1>Login</h1>
        
        <?php
        echo form_open('Main/login_validation');
        echo validation_errors();
        echo "<p>Email: ";
        echo form_input('email', $this->input->post('email'));
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>Password: ";
        echo form_password('password');
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo form_submit('login_submit', 'Login');
        echo "</p>";
      echo form_close();
        ?>
        
        <a href ='<?php echo base_url()."main/signup"; ?>'>Sign up!</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you facing any error? If yes, what is it?

Comment: I don't know how to insert that thing there, cause I have 2 forms.

Comment: You already have 2 forms. I don't get what you want to do with this? Merge them? Because the top one seems to be one with a nice layout and the bottom one is done with CodeIgniter. You can pass parameters to the CodeIgniter form helper functions to style them. How does this have anything to do with an associative array?

Comment: Solved, thanks all!